# How to find the cumulative sum of numbers in a list by adding a constant value?

Tags: python, numpy, sum, accumulate

Is it possible to create with `numpy` or another lib with only 2 pieces of information, `initial_value` added with a `constant_value`, with the next value in the list using the previous value?

```
initial_value = 5
constant_value = 3
desired_list_size = 7

ll = [initial_value]

for i in range(desired_list_size-1):
    next_value = ll[i] + constant_value
    ll.append(next_value)

print(ll)
#[5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you specifically mentioned numpy:

```py
import numpy as np

initial_value = 5
constant_value = 3
desired_list_size = 7

result = np.arange(desired_list_size) * constant_value + initial_value
```

This starts with a range from 0 to 7 (exclusive) then it multiplies each element by 3 and in the end it adds 5 to each element.

Note: the result size is actually equal to `desired_list_size` and not one larger as in your question.

Comment: probably you need `desired_list_size + 1`, if you want to form the array at one go.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> list(i* constant_value + initial_value for i in range(desired_list_size + 1))
[5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26]
```

or even easier,

```
>>> list(range(initial_value, (desired_list_size + 2) * constant_value, constant_value))
[5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26]
```